# Total sum of a numeric vector conditional on values from a character vector

Tags: r

x is a numeric vector and y is a character vector, both of the same length.
I have to obtain the total sum of x for each character in y.
So for example if y has the letters of the alphabet, the algorithm must sum all the values of x that indexed by a "A" and then all the values indexed by a "B", etc. It seems it can be done with the aggregate function but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: please make a reproducible example so we don't have to faff around creating dummy data frames.

Comment: `aggregate(x,factor(y),sum)` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test data, in a dataframe for convenience rather than two vectors:

```
> d = data.frame(x=runif(10),y=sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,TRUE))
> d
            x y
1  0.25927547 B
2  0.95012667 C
3  0.85133149 C
4  0.64658480 B
etc
```

Use `tapply`:

```
> tapply(d$x,d$y,sum)
       A        B        C 
1.547225 1.891884 2.666552
```

Convince yourself:

```
> sum(d$x[d$y=="A"])
[1] 1.547225
> sum(d$x[d$y=="B"])
[1] 1.891884
> sum(d$x[d$y=="C"])
[1] 2.666552
```

The `aggregate` function with a formula argument makes it easy to do with more than one column:

```
> d=data.frame(x=runif(10),y=sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,TRUE),z=sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,TRUE))
> d
           x y z
1  0.4166217 A C
2  0.5816940 B C
3  0.9915231 A C
4  0.7177323 B C
etc
```

We want to sum x within classes defined by y and z.

```
> aggregate(x~y+z,d,sum)
  y z         x
1 C A 1.6392171
2 B B 0.9389463
3 C B 0.3330299
4 A C 2.3748477
5 B C 1.2994263
```

Convince yourself:

```
> sum(d$x[d$y=="C" & d$z=="A"])
[1] 1.639217
> sum(d$x[d$y=="B" & d$z=="B"])
[1] 0.9389463
```

Note that C,A is a separate entry to A,C...

Comment: two thumbs up for your method! very efficient and elegant.

Comment: Does this works with double indexing? say a data frame with x,y and z?

Comment: Read the help for tapply and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Nice, can I count values using aggregate() ?